# how to delete files that not Exists show in db

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want write a code in php that
go to dir "upload" and see if is a file that dont Exists in my db 
and remove this file if it find.

```
$like = scandir(upload);
$myFile1 = upload; 
$myFile1 .= '/'; 
$myFile1 .= $like; 


$rs = mysql_query('SELECT url from blog');
while(list($url) = mysql_fetch_row($rs))
{
if($like != $url){
unlink($myFile1);
}

}
```

its write me a eror
    Warning: unlink(upload/Array) [function.unlink]:

Comment: Could you add your code to the question, please?

Comment: With the content you've specified.. Use a Cronjob, That's all your getting from me until you specify code, what you have tried, what isn't working right + examples of all

Comment: ' i write my code and in my site its give me this error' what errors?

Comment: @DarylGill Aggressive much? Bad day?  Note his lack of rep...probably doesn't understand what's going on. OP (user226): you should include all the information a person might need to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @andrewsi i write the code... and the eror is "Warning: unlink(upload/Array) [function.unlink"

Comment: @DarylGill i write now

Comment: @user2262606 - I think you need to look at how you're trying to do things. Your SQL statement will return every line in the table, so you can just add a WHERE clause to see if the one while you're looking at now is present. And you should also echo out what you're passing to unlink, as it's not formatted the right way.

Comment: @andrewsi  where of what?? .. write my your answer but i dont think that its the answer

Comment: how many files are we talking about ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scandir` returns an array of files; you'll need to step through that array, to check each one individually:

```
$like = scandir('upload');

foreach ($like as $thisFile) {
    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM blog WHERE url='$thisFile'");
    if (! mysql_num_rows($rs)) {
if($thisFile != "." and $thisFile != ".."){
         unlink ('upload/' . $thisFile);
}

    }
}
```

You're checking each file in that directory to see if it has an entry in the `blog` table; if it doesn't, it's passed to unlink. I've not tested this code, but it should give you an idea about how it runs.

A couple of notes:

1. What if there are directories in the directory? You should add some checking to skip over them. Don't forget that you'll have `./` and `../` in there.
2. What if there's an entry in the `blog` of `..\..\..\..\etc\passwd`? You should add some checking to make sure that `$thisFile` isn't something you don't want to delete.
3. This is using mysql; that's deprecated, and you should look at migrating to `mysqli` or `PDO` for the query. You can also then convert the query into a prepared statement, which will help it run more efficiently.

Comment: 1. i dont have directories in the directory 2. thank you but i still need something in your code for $thisFile i think maybe to add while{} before/after/in your code?

Comment: @user2262606 - you will always have `.` and `..` in a directory - they're pointers to the current directory and its parent. I'm not sure what your second point means, I'm afraid.

Comment: ok tnx its work i just change $like = scandir('upload');

foreach ($like as $thisFile) {
    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM blog WHERE url='$thisFile'");
    if (! mysql_num_rows($rs)) {
if($thisFile != "." and $thisFile != ".."){
         unlink ('upload/' . $thisFile);
}

    }
}